# C - Return failure from uint8_t function

Tags: c, return-value

I've got a function that gets a character from a UART device when the UART buffer is non-empty.

```
uint8_t getByte(void) {
    while(!uartCharsAvail(uartBase)) {
        // Wait for a character to become available
    }
    return uartGetChar(uartBase);
}
```

The problem is now I want to introduce a timeout so that the function will return a failure if it has waited too long.

```
uint32_t replyTimeout;
uint8_t getByte(void) {
    replyTimeout = 0;
    while(!uartCharsAvail(uartBase)) {
        // Wait for a character to become available
        if (replyTimeout++ > MAX_REPLY_TIME) {
            return -1;
        }
        delay(1);
    }
    return uartGetChar(uartBase);
}
```

The problem here of course being that I'm returning a negative number from a uint8_t function.

Is there a simple way to fix this? The only way I can think to do it is to make the function boolean and pass a uint8_t pointer as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, do it like all the C single-byte input/processing functions: Use an `int`, and all successful return-values are non-negative.

Comment: i suggest using clock cycles instead of incrementing a variable to measure timeout. e.g. clock() because using a variable is not very accurate, it may sometimes run faster or slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `int fgetc()`, use a negative value like `EOF` to indicate End-of-file (the serial port no longer available) or IO Error (e.g. timeout).

With data returns, use 0 to 255 which will not collide with `EOF`.

The key is that `getByte()` needs to return 257 different things (256 different bytes and timeout).  `uint8_t` lacks that range.

Comment: I'm not sure where I can find the definition of `fgetc()` but I take it I can just change `uint8_t getByte()` to `int getByte()` and it will work the way it's written?

Comment: @user3817250 Yes.  BTW: Google "fgetc c".

Comment: putting "fgetc c" into Google yields a pile of "how to use fgetc" type stuff but I didn't see anything that had the definition of fgetc.

Comment: @user3817250 `uartGetChar()` needs to return an unsigned integer type for "just change uint8_t getByte() to int getByte() and it will work".  Ref [WG14 N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §7.21.7.1 "The fgetc function"